# Solve nonlinear simultaneous equations with 3 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How to solve this system?

$$
X + Y + Z = A
$$
$$
X Y Z = B
$$
$$
X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = C
$$

For example: $(A, B, C )= (1, 2, 3)$

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: the system doesn't necessarily have a unique solution.

Comment: @DonThousand Can you explain more please?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

The l.h.s. of these equations are symmetric functions of X, Y, Z, of which the first and last are the elementary symmetric functions $s_1$ and $s_3$. Determine the value of the second elementary symmetric function
$$s_2=XY+YZ+ZX.$$
Once this is solved, you know that $X,Y,Z,$ are the roots of the cubic equation
$$t^3-s_1t^2+s_2t-s_3=0.$$
For your example, you should find the real root $2$ and the two nonreal cubic roots of unity.